# The axiom of regularity in a fact about $V_\omega$

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, ordinals

I'm working out the details  [in this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yybb.png) (from [here](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/cenzer/files/notes1020.pdf)), and I have some questions about the second part ("For the other direction, ...").

First, why is it possible to assume WLOG that $A$ is transitive?

Also, it says "Now take a minimal element $x_0$ in $B$ by the Axiom of Regularity". The axiom of regularity says that in any non-empty set, there is an element that doesn'h have elements in common with that set. I can see how this axiom is used in proving that $x_0\subseteq V_\omega$. But why is the author mentioning "a minimal element"? In particular, minimal in what sense? Is it some other form of the axiom of regularity?

My last question is not about the proof but rather about the statement of the theorem being proved. In another textbook, I found the following statement: "$x\in V_\omega$ iff $x$ is well-founded and $trcl(x)$ is finite", and there's a remark saying that the condition that $x$ be well-founded cannot be omitted. I believe the statement "$trcl(x)$ is finite" is equivalent to "$x$ is hereditarily finite", and if so, the theorem being proved says "$x\in V_\omega$ iff $trcl(x)$ is finite", omitting the condition that $x$ be well-founded. Is well-foundedness still used implicitly in the proof (maybe when applying the axiom of regularity), and should it be included in the statement of the theorem?

Comment: We can assume that $A$ is transitively closed because $A$ is hereditarily finite iff $tr(A)$ is hereditarily finite. (Proving this from definitions should be a good exercise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in $\mathsf{ZF}$, every set is well-founded, as well-foundedness of a set $x$ means that $\in$ is a well-founded relation on $\mathrm{tc}(x)$, which is true by the axiom of regularity.

The term *minimal* in the author's argument means exactly what you are writing, note that an element $y \in x$ with $y \cap x = \emptyset$ is minimal with respect to the relation $\in$ on $x$.

For your first question: If $A$ is not transitive, consider $A' = \mathrm{tc}(A)$. Then $A'$ is hereditarily finite and $A' \in V_\omega \iff A \in V_\omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about the first question -- why is it possible to assume without loss of generality that $A$ is a transitive set?

Comment: As I was reproducing the proof on my own, I found that I don't understand why $B$ is nonempty (which is needed to apply the axiom of regularity). $B$ is just $A\setminus V_\omega$. If $B$ were empty, this would mean $A\subseteq V_\omega$. But I don't see why this cannot be the case. Does this somehow imply that $A\in V_\omega$, contradicting the assumption $A\notin V_\omega$? On a similar note, at the end of the proof the author says that $x_0\in A\setminus V_\omega$, showing that $A\not\subseteq V_\omega$, but how does this contradict the initial assumption $A\notin V_\omega$?

Comment: Better to ask a new question (and link to this one), but I'll try to give an answer in a comment: If $A \subseteq V_\omega$ is finite, say $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$, then for each $I$, there is an $n_i < \omega$ such that $a_i \in V_{n_i}$. Taking $n = \max_i n_i$, we have $a_i \in V_n$ for each $I$, that is $A \subseteq V_n$ or $A \in V_{n+1} \subseteq V_\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is hereditarily finite but $A\not\in V_{\omega}=\cup_{n\in \omega}P(V_n)$

then $\forall n\in\omega\,(A\not\subset V_n)$

so $\forall n\in\omega\,(trcl(A)\not\subset V_n)$... (because $trcl(A)\supset A$)...

so $trcl(A)\not\in \cup_{n\in\omega}P(V_n)= V_{\omega}.$

So if  A is hereditarily finite but $A\not\in V_{\omega}$ then there exists a  hereditarily finite transitive set (namely,$trcl(A)\,)$ that is not in $V_{\omega}$. This explains  "WLOG $A$ is transitive" because the book gives a proof that a hereditarily finite transitive set  that is not in $V_{\omega}$ is impossible.